# Purpose of passing parameters in collection in java

Tags: java

I see a return method that has parameter like this:

```
return new HashSet<Books>(bookService.getBookData(Books.class,customer.getVisitingCustomer);
```

But I am not able to understand the idea of passing Books.class, customer.getVisitingCustomer as parameter. I also sometimes
see more than two parameters?

Can someone explain me the purpose of passing parameters in collection?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `HashSet`, but the implementation of `getBookData(Class<? extends Book> ... pBooks)`, from the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

The code (fixed) is *presumably*

> ```
> return new HashSet(bookService.getBookData(Books.class,
>         customer.getVisitingCustomer()));
> ```

and that involves three operations;

1. `customer.getVisitingCustomer()`
2. `bookService.getBookData(Books.class, <STEP 1>)`
3. `return new HashSet(<STEP 2>)`

The first is retrieving a *visiting customer* from the `customer`. The second invokes a `bookService` method that takes `Books.class` (presumably to perform some form of [Object-Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)). The third then forces the results of that method to be unique (a `Set`).